# Python - scraping web: urllib2 enough or scrapy/selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

For my seo tool I am scraping entire HTML from sites to analyse it later.
This will go trough - 500 different domains/urls every day. (already have those saved in db)

I am just testing now but encountering different problems like bad server response, captchas... Here is my urlib code:

```
try:                
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=1))
    opener.addheaders = [
        # ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13'),
        # ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
        # ('Accept-Language', 'en-gb,en;q=0.5'),
        # ('Accept-Encoding', 'deflate'),
        # ('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'),
        # ('Keep-Alive', '115'),
        # ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
        # ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0'),
        ('Referer', 'https://google.com'),                   
    ]
    html = opener.open(url).read()                
except URLError as e:
    if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        # print 'We failed to reach a server.'
        # print 'Reason: ', e.reason, url
        html = ''
    elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
        # print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
        # print 'Error code: ', e.code, url
        html = ''
```

Is this suitable foundation to build on? Or should I look into something else(selenium is first thing that comes to mind)?

Comment: Ask yourself this question, **"do I need JavaScript ?"** If so, selenium is the answer.

Comment: No, JS is not important - I am mostly worried about bad responses and captchas due to this being bot.

Comment: If JS isn't important it can be achieved with urllib2. My 2 cents: Test the post/get on your browser and emulate them via code. Use live http headers for firefox or similar tool.

Comment: @NemaGa, depending on what kind of captchas you ancounter. If new reCaptchas then you'd better plug in [Selenium solution](http://scraping.pro/recaptcha-solve-selenium-python/) that might help. If  typical text captchas, refer to [Bypass CAPTCHA api](http://bypasscaptcha.com/api_doc/) to leverage within python.